# Удаление из строки всего, кроме цифр

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string cleaned(string s1)
{
    string cl;
    for (int i=0;i<s1.length();++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(s1[i]))
        {
            cl[i]=s1[i];
        }
    }
    return cl;
}

int main()
{
string s1="213asd123asd2134";
cout<<cleaned(s1)<<endl;
}
```

Проблема в том, что в консоли ничего не выводится. (Не уверен что сделал правильно)

Comment: Вызов `operator[]` подразумевает существование элемента с указанным индексом. У вас же, строка `cl` пустая, а вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему элементу (`cl[i]`). Используйте `push_back` например.

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Проблема тут не в том, что "в консоли ничего не выводится", а в том, что программа падает.

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет ничего в `cl` - как вы собираетесь писать в `i`-й символ? Да даже если бы и было место - то у вас просто были бы разрозненные цифры...

Замените

```
cl[i]=s1[i];
```

на

```
cl +=s1[i];
```

И, кстати, незачем передавать строку в функцию по значению - достаточно константной ссылки.

P.S. не по делу :) - в связи с вопросами оптимизации в соседнем ответе у меня для VC++2017 лучший результат получился при

```
string cl;
cl.reserve(s.length());
for(int i = 0, l = s.length(); i < l; ++i)
    if (s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0')
        cl += s[i];
```

Кому не лень - можно посмотреть [тут](https://ideone.com/pgFwVi).

Comment: Естественно, что результат будет лучше, если  в цикле не вызывается функция

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `isdigit`, как правило, реализуется как макрос или inline-функция, а не как вызываемая функция.

Comment: в  inline-функции, тоже выполняются же действия посложнее чем простое сравнение, приведенные вами.

Answer (score -1):

Я полностью  согласен с предыдущим ответчиком, вам нужно cl[i] = s1[i] заменить на cl += s1[i]; однако на мой взгляд

```
if (isdigit(s1[i]))
    {
        cl += s1[i];
    }
```

работает медленне, чем следующия реализация:

```
if (s1[i]-'0'>=0 && s1[i]-'0'<=9)
    {
        cl+=s1[i];
    }
```

Я говорю это, так как вычитать из символа '0' и получать номер этого символа намного удобнее и много где используется (например для определения заглавная буква или нет). Лучше так, чем искать всякие непонятные команды и специальные функции.

Comment: Тогда уж `if (s1[i] >= '0' && s1[i] <= '9')` хотя не очень понятно, с какой стати это должно работать быстрее `isdigit`, которая делает то же самое.

Comment: isdigit требует подключения библиотеки <cctype>. Но в данном случае, я соглашусь что библиотека не нужна, и что проверяется символ, поэтому все работает хорошо. Но если бы проверялась строка на то, является ли она числом, то isdigit уже не помог бы.

Comment: Ну, на этом уровне оптимизации я бы рекомендовал обратный порядок - `if (s1[i] <= '9' && s1[i] >= '0')` - так на буквах будет выполняться только одна проверка, а не обе. Ну и с самого начала резервировать место в памяти для строки `cl`.